# Constructing nouns from verbs that have taken effect

Tags: nominalization

My native language is agglutinative, we can create a noun from the native word for "to blow one's nose."

Let's say a *used napkin or hankie*. Can I define the equivalent native word in English as *that which has been used to blow one's nose?* Or is it *that which which..*?

Or something *that was used for sleeping?*
Can I say, *that which has been slept on* or *that which has been slept upon?*

Answer (score 3):

"That which is slept on" in English is a *periphrasis* for **bed** (or anything bed-like).

English combines in a different way:

**snot-rag**  (informal)

**nose-rag**  (ditto)

"snot" is the colloquial word for nasal mucus.

**rag** is the informal term for a small piece of cloth used for cleaning purposes (compare **dish-rag**)

P.S. We can also say things like this:

> The bed was such a rumpled mess of quilts and blankets that it was difficult to tell **the sleeper**  from **the slept-on**.

**Sleeper** there consists of the verb **sleep** with a suffix that means "one who does [the verb's action]" and **the slept-on** there is a sort of ad-hoc metonymic nominal reference via  an adjective formed from the past participle of the verb **sleep** and the preposition **on**. The main attribute of a bed is that it gets slept on.  But we could never say "I need to get a new slept-on."

Comment: At the absolute margins of credible usage, I think it would be possible to say something like *I want a snot rag, not a snotty rag!* to mean *I want a **clean** hanky, not a used one!*